# Preventing "This is a late answer" preambles

Tags: discussion, answers, late-answers

With late answers, an all too common pattern (or antipattern) is the well-intentioned, but gratuitous, preamble, such as "This is too late for the questioner but might help someone else" or "Although the question was already answered, this is the top Google result so here's another option".

I'm sure we're all familiar with comments like this. As I say, they're well-intentioned, but the fact is they're also not adding any value and whether they are present or not is completely arbitrary. Most questions are evergreen, it's just expected that new answers can arise, and there's a clear indication of the post time. So I would suggest these preambles be discouraged and moderated away.

Is it reasonable to remove those preambles?

---

Update (April 30 2015) - Thanks everyone for the answers here. Some people have interpreted this as being about contrasting an answer with other answers, which I think makes perfect sense. I'm only talking about specifically saying the answer is late. I'm not saying the answers have to look like perfectly independent options, because the posts do have public timestamps attached and it's reasonable to expect the answer set to evolve over time, with newer answers explaining, in some cases, why they are adding value.

Comment: Sure, just go ahead and edit them out. Or did you mean something else?

Comment: I've done this once or twice myself. Usually because there are already highly voted answers, but I want potential new viewers to know straight away that my answer is considerably newer, hence the lower (or no) votes it has. IOW I'm making the distinction so people don't assume it has no votes because it is no good - most viewers won't look at the timestamp when skimming through. Then again, I only leave late answers if it's good and actually adds something.

Comment: @Deduplicator I wouldn't want to edit them out if there wasn't an official policy/interpretation about them.

Comment: @slugster Fair point about highlighting it, but I feel like that should be the job of the SO interface, otherwise it unfairly/disproportionately rewards that %ge of late answerers who do leave a comment like this.

Comment: I agree with @slugster that it's useful to highlight new answers that might not have been considered while the question was "fresh" and unanswered. In fact, I'd go a step further and suggest somehow highlighting answers that are posted after the accepted answer.

Comment: @slugster One problem with this is that what's new now will not be new forever. What will people say when they add another answer in a couple of years? "This answer is even newer than the new answer by slugster"?

Comment: @RetoKoradi You have a good point. I'm not against this suggestion, by and large I think it's good. I was simply relating when I've left that type of text in an answer - not saying that it's correct or anything.

Comment: @slugster that sounds good, but I doubt it's necessary. I like answering old questions when I think there's something to add. I've found that when I provide value, I get upvoted, even if my answer started out looking ignored.

Comment: You won't be able to prevent users from adding preambles unless they were made aware beforehand of the fact that they're unnecessary. For the vast majority of users, even those who read documentation, by the time this happens they would probably already have had their first late-answer preamble edited out after-the-fact.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think such a disclaimer is not necessary. It isn't really bad on long answers, but it can detract from the content for short answers.

**What can I do instead?**

If answerers really want to convey that they know what they are doing by answering, they can comment on their own answer. A comment is just that: a comment. Whether it is a meta-comment (in the sense of a disclaimer we're talking about here) or a comment about content, it doesn't make a difference.

Comments have a lesser visibility, so I think doing it this way doesn't detract from the content of the answer.

Another possibility is moving the disclaimer to the bottom of the answer inside of a superscript element: `<sup>disclaimer</sup>`.

Comment: This makes sense, comment policy is a lot more flexible as it ultimately doesn't matter much, and various types of meta-comments are fairly common.

Answer (score 49):

I was going to stay quiet, on the basis that I always try and avoid an argument, so despite my misgivings, I'm going to identify myself as someone who uses this as an introductory sentence to an answer quite frequently. In fact I was sensitive enough to worry you were talking about me specifically, but a wiser me knows that is just normal paranoia. (But then in *another* meta discussion, someone *was* talking about me specifically....)

I wrote that sentence as a reaction to feedback from other users (who may have been around on SO longer or have higher rep scores than me) who gave me indications that they had strong negative reactions to quite old questions being bumped up by my answers; irrespective of whether the answer was useful.

I felt it said "yes, I know this is an old subject but I didn't answer it by accident, I felt it useful and informative to answer it; so please don't treat me like a some idiot who is answering at random...."

Another reason that I might use a question preamble is to explain why a question was answered when it is not obvious that answering would be the best action. A question could be editing, downvoted, flagged or commented, separately or in combination. I've sometimes looked at a question for weeks thinking what is the best approach to something that has not been addressed by anyone else, but is clearly an issue for the questioner (or the wider population of users). Many are so highly upvoted that it indicates that several people thought it was good enough for an answer. I've flagged quite a few for which the flags aged away (> 200). The remaining option would be to improve and/or answer. For those who may not have done the investigation that I did, an explanatory preamble would help in understanding why an answer was being seen at this late stage. I did get input from another higher rep user that said that such hints might be helpful, when what would otherwise have seemed like an answer "coming out of the blue".

I have discovered (for myself) a technique of sitting with the "active" questions in a browser tag and noting any new activity. This was how I noticed the appearance your question, for example. I suspect many sit on their favourite tag and use it like intellectual social media site. They see someone answering an old question akin to re-tweeting some old fact from many years ago, or sharing some out of date fashion tip, and consequently react negatively to what they see as someone acting outside the norms of the clique. A kind of xenophobia if you will.

I think it a little unfair to say it should be banned, but then it was useful to highlight it.

Several of my answer had preambles which were a kind of meta-answer. I've take more recently to putting the meta-answer in a comment immediately after the answer. If I adopt that trend then perhaps you might get less irritated by the behaviour.

I do still have misgivings about putting my head above the parapet for this brief period, and will go back to quietly generating answers. I might add, that my experience at such interactions goes back to the dawn of usenet and before. This experience causes me to type carefully....

Comment: Thanks for sharing your rationale for this Brian and I assure you, you're paranoia isn't justified :) If those answers were from you, I wouldn't actually recall (and also it would make you quite prolific if they were all from you in my random observations!).

Comment: "yes, I know this is an old subject but I didn't answer it by accident, I felt it useful and informative to answer it; so please don't treat me like a some idiot who is answering at random....". No-one should be seen as an idiot because they are adding a new answer; I know in forums people write *bump* to acknowledge the weirdness of replying 3 yrs later, but it's just a normal thing to do on SO. So maybe that's partly about managing users' expectations as well, or some design element. But also if these comments weren't present, there would be less feeling that it's unusual.

Comment: "For those who may not have done the investigation that I did, an explanatory preamble would help in understanding why an answer was being seen at this late stage." I can understand this and in fact, it's really no different to a timely (ie non-late) answer that does the same thing, ie contrasting itself to other answers. It's more the generic "I know this is late" comments I'm referring to.

Comment: The crucial thing, speaking as someone who frequently hits Recommend Deletion on meaninglessly similar answers added years later and who *also* carefully edits out such necro-disclaimers *without* flagging the post, is this: does your answer explain its own merits and potential pitfalls, inline, encapsulating the reasons it should exist without relying on the context? If so, it's a good answer, whether six seconds late or six years.

Comment: Sometimes all the requirements the OP put in surrounding the core question makes it so overly specific that it is largely useless to others, but I might come along and want to give a direct answer to the core question that would be useful to others, but include a similar preamble to indicate I am answering the core question, irrespective of the fluff in the question.  One could argue whether this is valid approach, but it adds useful value often and I've had a few such answers rise above previous answers in such a case.

Comment: @AaronLS Would you consider asking a new, clean question and self-answering instead?

Comment: IMHO part of the problem is that many assume an answer to an old question has no value, while posts at SE are supposed to be useful in the long term (too). Hence necromancy should be encouraged! http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/254753/248268

Answer (score 31):

If you see it and want it removed, there is no reason not to as it makes the answer more clear. That being said, there is also no reason to seek out this type of preamble in order to edit it out. It would be a terrible waste of time, and to be honest, the preamble does not significantly detract from the answer.

For the most part questions are discouraged from having fluff so they don't waste everyone's time. For answers, it is less of an issue (although still advised against).

As for preventing this with moderation, or some sort of script, I don't really see that happening. It isn't significant enough to warrant that much time, and it would be rather difficult to predict what part of the answer actually was a preamble versus what was not.

Comment: Not looking for a script or active obliteration policy, more just asking to get some kind of consensus as to whether it's a valid thing or not.

Comment: @mahemoff - Anything that makes an answer less clear will hinder the amount of upvotes that answer gets, so from a poster's perspective it is undesirable. However, it is not entirely invalid, and especially not really frowned upon if it only happens once or twice by a poster. In general, it is just fluff and is not required. Without it, the answer would still be the same content. So, in my opinion it is in the grey area of valid, along the lines of not doing any damage an thus being overlooked with indifference. One piece of advice: if you do edit this out, and the OP reverses, let it be.

Comment: If it's considered to fall in the gray area, I wouldn't bother to edit it out.

Comment: @mahemoff: It's on the darker end of the gray area: it definitely shouldn't be posted and should be removed when other edits need to be made to the question, but it's not a good enough reason to edit on its own. There's a fair number of anti-patterns in this group.

Comment: Good way to put it. Would be interesting to see these gray/darkgray patterns listed somewhere.

Answer (score 6):

I personally do this since I believe it is the right thing to do if you are going to drag a 2-3 year old thread to the top of the question pile again.

Normally this is done out of courtesy to the other answerers who may have last edited the thread 2-3 years ago and may, in turn, suffer from your own answer. One example could be that you provide an updated answer which makes others get downvoted (which is endorsed by this community) since they are old and yours is new.

Other times it is put on to prevent the inevitable comment of "stop necroing". These comments are a real problem and I have seen them before now from over zealous other answerers or visitors who instinctively see necroing as bad or feel hurt from losing rep since they didn't update their answer.

If the answer is short enough that "This is too late for the questioner but might help someone else" detracts from the content then you must ask yourself if this late answer is really worth digging up an old thread and necroing. Such answers are problematic with or without the blurb and may suffer in the Low Quality or Not An Answer queues.

So personally I do not see the harm in these blurbs (so long as they are short and straight to the point) and I will continue writing them.

Comment: I haven't seen any examples of "stop necroing" on SO. If they are there, I think they are in the minority and (unlike the ambiguous question asked here) there's no question that would be out of order.

Comment: @mahemoff hmm maybe it was wrong to put the quotation marks around it, however, the comments come in many forms, one commonly seen as well is "this thread is very old, things have changed since, please make a new question"

Comment: I wasn't taking the quote literally, just haven't seen comments like that, but maybe they're more prevalent in some topics.

Answer (score 6):

The challenge with a "ban" on preambles is that they can in fact be useful to highlight why a new answer is now appropriate. Circumstances change, new insights are obtained, and these may lead to better answers. If this is the case, it is important to point out these insights/circumstances before giving an answer that depends on them.

Now, a preamble such as the "might help someone else" is not such a new insight, and meaningless - a large part of the justification of SO is that it might help someone else. So, remove it. Not because it's a preamble, but because it's not helpful.